# Shortened URL not Recognized

Tags: internet-explorer, url, twitter, url-shortener

I am using a widget to generate a list of tweets from multiple users. Because twitter uses URL shortening, the output of t.co(insert rest of URL) is not recognized by any browser other than Chrome. Is there a workaround to this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Firefox and a number of other browsers handle the t.co forwards without trouble.

Still, if you just want a script that looks up where it forwards to, I wrote this the other day:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import requests

fwdurl = raw_input("Enter the shortened URL in its entirety: ")
r = requests.get(fwdurl)

print("""
The shortened URL forwards to:

    %s
""" % r.url)
```

Obviously it requires Python and the requests module.  It will, however, resolve any shortened URL.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I'll see if I can use this

Comment: You're welcome. Like I said it needs [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) and in the unlikely event you need to check a forwarding service that uses HTTPS (e.g. seeing exactly where https://google.com goes) then you'll need to change the get line to: r = requests.get(fwdurl, verify=False)